# A certain obscure FOSS script made for my archaic motherboard to perform a very specific function fails to run. Can anyone please explain why?

Tags: motherboard, script, github, windows-installer, open-source

So, I have a motherboard, [MSI H81M-P33](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/H81M-P33.html), and I have a freshly bought PWM fan. Unfortunately, my motherboard's BIOS does not allow me to reduce the RPM curve of my fans below 50%, which makes them unbelievably loud. However, there is a temporary workaround using MSI software, seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZn9xnue0Dk), which works wonderfully until you shut down your PC (or, as I have found out, close MSI Command Center before putting it to sleep, apparently). Thankfully, some person has made a workaround script [here](https://github.com/Nithanim/fancontrol4msi), which load a custom configuration file on boot, essentially bypassing all the fuss with reapplying temporary workaround on boot manually. But, unfortunately, I fail to run it, at any FAN_ID configuration, and get this error message in PowerShell whenever I want to apply the aforementioned script:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\1\1.exe -3;A;1E;2D;37;28;37;41;4B;77
Config read!
Started service
COMMAND NOT SENT!
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Can anybody more code-apt than me please look at all the possible factors as to why I get this error message and how can possibly the original piece of source code (or my argument line) be modified to make it functional for my motherboard? Or perhaps there is an alternative workaround for setting up my motherboard to desired RPM curve altogether?

Much thanks.